# flutter: how to style NavigationBar

Tags: flutter, dart, navigationbar

I want to match a figma design of a `bottomNavigationBar`:

[image]

this is the code:

```
return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBar(
        onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
          logDebug('selected index: $index');
          setState(() {
            selectedPageIndex = index;
          });
        },
        selectedIndex: selectedPageIndex,
        destinations: <NavigationDestination>[
          const NavigationDestination(
            selectedIcon: Icon(
              Icons.home,
              size: 37,
              color: primaryColor,
            ),
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.home_outlined,
              size: 37,
              color: primaryColor,
            ),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          const NavigationDestination(
            selectedIcon: Icon(
              Icons.ev_station,
              size: 37,
              color: primaryColor,
            ),
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.ev_station_outlined,
              size: 37,
              color: primaryColor,
            ),
            label: 'someLable',
          ),
          NavigationDestination(
            selectedIcon: const Icon(Icons.car_repair),
            icon: Image.asset(
              'assets/images/car_repair.png',
              width: 40,
              color: primaryColor,
            ),
            label: 'Services',
          ),
          const NavigationDestination(
            selectedIcon: Icon(
              Icons.stars,
              size: 37,
              color: primaryColor,
            ),
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.stars_outlined,
              size: 37,
              color: primaryColor,
            ),
            label: 'Points',
          ),
          const NavigationDestination(
            selectedIcon: Icon(
              Icons.person_2,
              size: 37,
              color: primaryColor,
            ),
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.person_2_outlined,
              size: 37,
              color: primaryColor,
            ),
            label: 'Profile',
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Text("hellp"),
      ),
    );
```

but the problem is the final look of the navigation bar looked like this
[image]

is there's any way i can change the styling of indcitor to match figma design (colors can be changed later)

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What are you exactly looking for? Is it the selected element background only?

Comment: selected item background and bottom indecitaor

Answer (score 0):

The logic behind your indicator can be whatever you want.
In the Figma design, the indicator is covering the full Icon and Label, while in your design, it's just covering the Icon.

If that is your only issue, figure out the logic for the element that is being filled and adapt it to become the full width and height of the whole button, not just the Icon.

With the same logic you currently have, you can change the appearance of the indicator as you please.

Comment: I tried to make the background color cover both icon and label but I couldn't find any thing solution same for the green indicator